# Finding the trace of a continuous gradient

Tags: vector-analysis

A very typical question in my vector analysis textbook concerns the gradient of a point in a Scalar field. For instance, given a temperature distribution, what direction would a fly in position $  (x,y,z)$  have to move in order to achieve the momentary highest temperature increase?

This is a very trivial example, but I came to wonder about what route the fly might take to achieve the highest temperature when moving from point $  a $ to $  b$ , i.e. what curve does the fly trace when always following the gradient form a stating point?

What methods could be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Alright that's true, but if the fly only has local data and decides to follow the gradient, what curve would that trace. Is it possible to find an explicit formula for the curve.

Comment: Good question by the way. Made me think a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a curve $\gamma$ such that:

$$ \frac{d }{dt} \gamma(t) = \nabla F$$

With $\gamma(t) =  (x(t) , y(t) )$. We get:

$$ \dot{x} = \partial_x F = P_1 (x,y)$$

$$ \dot{y} = \partial_y F=P_2(x,y)$$

If we solved the two coupled set of differential equation above for $\gamma(t)$, we can see the curve from a starting point $(x_o,y_o)$ as the fly follows the gradient.

---

An example: Consider $F(x,y)=xy$, then:

$$ \dot{x} = y$$
And,

$$ \dot{y} = x$$

We can write :

$$ \ddot{x} = x$$

$$ x(t)= C_1 e^{\lambda t} + C_2 e^{-\lambda t}$$
$$ y(t) =\lambda \left[ C_1 e^{\lambda} t - C_2 e^{-\lambda t} \right]$$

If the fly began at the point $(1,1)$ at t=0, we find that:

$$ \gamma(t)= e^t( 1,1)$$

I.e: as we increase from $t=0$, the fly moves further and further outwards in the (1,1) direction in the plane it moves.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. Good job and thanks for taking your time to answer my question. :D